# Using dynamically named form fields inside of ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

My code:

```
<div class='span3' ng-repeat="intFilter in intFilters" 
    ng-class="{ 'has-error' : filter.{{intFilter.name}}.$invalid &&
                             !filter.{{intFilter.name}}.$pristine }">
    <label>{{intFilter.name}}</label>
    <select class="metricFilter" ng-init="intFilter.selectedOp=operators[0]" 
        ng-model="intFilter.selectedOp" ng-options='op for op in operators' >
    </select>
    <input name="{{intFilter.name}}" id="{{intFilter.name}}" 
           class='inputFilter' ng-model='intFilter.input' 
           placeholder="integer value" ng-pattern="onlyNumbers">
    <p style="color:red; font-size:11px;" 
       ng-show="filter.{{intFilter.name}}.$error.pattern" class="help-block">     
       {{intFilter.name}} is invalid!
    </p>
</div>
```

... where you can assume that `{{intFilter.name}}` outputs `Borehole Depth`.

Validation error messages are displaying from the page load itself. The space character between Borehole and Depth is giving error for me I think.

Is this is the right approach?

Comment: It's not obvious what you're getting at here. The code is clear, but can you provide more detail about what the problem is? For example, please elaborate on what you mean when you say "above {{intFilter.name}} is Borehole Depth"

Comment: yes, filter.Borehole Depth.$error.pattern  is this valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use interpolation with the `name` attribute on your inputs. The issue has been under [active discussion](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1404) in the Angular community. Currently, unless you want to create a $decorator, your best bet is to use `ng-form`:

```
<form name="filter">
  <div class='span3' ng-repeat="intFilter in intFilters">
     <ng-form name="innerForm">
        <div ng-class="{ 'has-error' : innerForm.input.$invalid && !innerForm.input.$pristine }">
          <label>{{intFilter.name}}</label>
          <select class="metricFilter" ng-init="intFilter.selectedOp=operators[0]" 
              ng-model="intFilter.selectedOp" ng-options='op for op in operators' >
          </select>
          <input name="input" id="{{intFilter.name}}" 
                 class='inputFilter' ng-model='intFilter.input' 
                 placeholder="integer value" ng-pattern="/[0-9]+/">
          <p style="color:red; font-size:11px;" 
             ng-show="innerForm.input.$error.pattern" class="help-block">     
             {{intFilter.name}} is invalid!
          </p>
          {{intFilter.input}}
      </div>
    </ng-form>
  </div>
</form>
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/K1jP5sMDbzL1PvyZKPVn?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use interpolation ({{}}) inside ng-class, if `filter` is the form name, then ng-class should look something like this:

```
ng-class="{ 'has-error' : filter[intFilter.name].$invalid && !filter[intFilter.name].$pristine }"
```

Comment: how can I use it in ng-show="filter.{{intFilter.name}}.$error.pattern" this line

Comment: The same, use filter[intFilter.name].$error.pattern

Comment: Hard to say, maybe onlyNumbers is not a correct regexp. In any case you can add this line {{filter[intFilter.name].$error | json}} instead of '{{intFilter.name}} is invalid!' to see error object on the page.

Comment: @ArtemLatyshev is correct about ng-class, but there is a more fundamental problem here involving dynamic form field names: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1404